# Npm installs fails on cloudbees jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, cloudbees

With a strange checksum error, And I can't figure what's wrong. 
it happens both when I installed Npm and node as cloudbees support suggested and when I used node-js-jenkins plugin. both when using -g and not using -g flag. what's wrong?

getting this log:

```
> Unpacking http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.7/node-v0.11.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
> to
> /scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_0.11.7
> on s-68b3777c $
> /scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_0.11.7/bin/npm
> install -g grunt-cli phantomjs jshint npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli npm http 200
> https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-0.1.9.tgz npm http
> 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint npm http 200
> https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.1.11.tgz npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs/-/phantomjs-1.9.2-2.tgz npm http
> 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-0.1.9.tgz npm
> http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs/-/phantomjs-1.9.2-2.tgz
> npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.1.11.tgz npm
> ERR! Error: shasum check failed for
> /home/jenkins/tmp/npm-399-NkLy1zBO/1381868137921-0.8519227004144341/tmp.tgz
> npm ERR! Expected: eb5108fef9ba5ddebb830983f572d242e49e3f96 npm ERR!
> Actual:   b80f62e5bdfed4297392de2ed8711d5aff5e5742 npm ERR!     at
> /scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_0.11.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:38:8
> npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous>
> (/scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_0.11.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:85:7)
> npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:125:20) npm
> ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:896:16 npm ERR!     at
> process._tickCallback (node.js:317:11) npm ERR! If you need help, you
```

Any clues? suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned to be between the `node.js` version I was calling (the 'devel' 0.11.7) and cloudbees fedora linux version. reverting to a node.js **stable** version sort of solved this (still other problems with them..)